# Map problem when passing it as model to view in grails

Tags: grails, model, dictionary, view

In a controller, I have populated a map that has a string as key and a list as value; in the gsp, I try to show them like this:

```
<g:each in="${sector}" var="entry" >
  <br/>${entry.key}<br/>
  <g:each in="${entry.value}" var="item" >
    ${item.name}<br/>
  </g:each>
</g:each>
```

The problem is that item is considered as string, so I get the exception

```
Error 500: Error evaluating expression [item.name] on line [11]:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: 
java.lang.String
```

Any hints on how to fix it other than doing the find for the item explicitly in the gsp ?

Comment: Are u sure that you code is correct? The exception thrown is "No such property: nombre for class..". What is nombre?
For more information to help you, could you print out the result of ${item}?

Comment: sorry about that, I mixed versions, but the error is the same

Comment: @fabien7474: nombre is Spanish for name

Comment: Do this, print out sector, and print out item ... it seems like when sector is constructed, it's not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the poc which works fine for me

> ```
> class Item{   
>      String name 
> }
> ```
>
> List items = [new Item(name:"laptop" ,
>   new Item(name:"mouse")]
>
> Map sector =[:]
>
> sector.manager = items
>
> sector.manager.each{item->
>
> ```
> println item.name
> ```
>
> }

Even If it doesn't work, Try declaring Map sector as

> Map < String, List < Item > > sector =[:]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem happens in the view with the gsp tags, not in the controller.